# Services in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I'm learning AngularJS and I've a little problem for services. The official tutorial gives an example for custom services with REST :

```
angular.module('phonecatServices', ['ngResource']).
    factory('Phone', function($resource){
        return $resource('phones/:phoneId.json', {}, {
            query: {method:'GET', params:{phoneId:'phones'}, isArray:true}
        });
    });
```

So I made the same code with different names/url and it works.

I would like to pass a parameter to this service (an id in the url).
I tried to use $routeParams in it but it didn't work. Finally I found an other way to declare several function in the same service, so I made that :

```
factory('Article', function($resource) {
    return {
        getList: function(categoryId) {
                return $resource('http://...', {
                    query: {method:'GET', isArray:true}
                });
            }
        }
    })
```

But it doesn't work for a REST call (with return 'Hello' for example, it's ok).

Do you know how do that ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are not passing in the parameter into the query function.

```
angular.module('Article', ['ngResource']).
    factory('Phone', function($resource){
        return return $resource('http://.../:articleId', {
                query: {method:'GET', isArray:true}
            });
    });
});
```

And then in your controller.

```
Article.query({
  articleId : someVar
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works. I just would like to know if a service with several functions is the good way in AngularJS or not ?

Comment: Look at the doc page, http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource in your resource setup you can supply custom functions (charge in the credit card example), assuming I follow your question.